# Where should I report a possible Freeciv / Ubuntu suspend problem?

Tags: 18.04, suspend

Suspend fails in Ubuntu 18.04 after playing Freeciv but not immediately. maybe two or three days. Sooner the more I play.

Ubuntu 18.04
Freeciv (gtk2) 2.5.10-1

I can’t prove this but I installed and started playing on an old computer and in a few days had suspend fail. Reboot and repeat. When I checked my notes and saw only Freeciv and Ubuntu updates done in that time, I rebooted and stopped playing and haven’t had a suspend failure since.

I installed it on a new computer and saw the same problem just taking a little longer. Reboot, stop playing and no suspend failures.

Comment: I don't know, the catch all could be `linux`, but it's more likely `upower` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/upower).  I'm not sure how `freeciv` (which will install https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/freeciv-client-gtk) would impact upower, but it's something you'd need a *dev* to see anyway. I'd suggest `ubuntu-bug upower` and be as clear as you can (with general observations) , including a (a) "steps to re-create" section and (b) "expected results", (c) "actual results" for your issue. Even better is look up https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Thanks. I ran the unbuntu-bug on the old computer, typed up some notes and am waiting for the bug reporting to continue.

Comment: Submitted it as a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freeciv/+bug/1867932